# Receiving a truncated string value in a SQL Server query from PHP script

Tags: php, sql-server, string, pdo

I am executing a SQL query inside a PHP script. The query is executed against a SQL Server database, using the PDO class. I am retrieving the results of the query using `$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`.

One of the columns in the result is a string that could be in excess of 256 characters, but when I access this value in PHP, the string is always truncated at 256 characters. The value itself is basically just a sentence i.e., reasonable for its length to exceed 256 characters, but not 1024 characters.

The MS SQL DB stores the data in (effectively) a `VARCHAR(1024)` column. If I run the query in Visual Studio, there is no truncation - I get the full string returned.

I can obviously modify the query and the PHP code (not the configuration), but not the MS SQL DB.

Where is the truncation happening? How do I retrieve the full string in my PHP code?

Comment: please add some code in question

Comment: thank you for your time - stumbled on a solution (below)

Answer (score 1):

I tried a few things and found something that worked.

In the MS SQL query, I wrapped the offending field in a `CAST(x as TEXT)`. 
This seems to have done the trick.

As a record of some of the other things I tried:

The comments on this page make reference to retrieving large strings.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-query.php

The suggestions are to execute these lines as part of the PHP script:

```
$conn->query('SET TEXTSIZE 2147483647');
ini_set ( 'mssql.textlimit' , '2147483647' );
ini_set ( 'mssql.textsize' , '2147483647' );
```

Some people seem to say that the query alone works; others say that the php ini lines did the trick.